# get_member() returns NoneType with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to coding and i'm seriously stuck. Been going through the API and trying to figure this out on and off for a few days and now I have to reach out for help.

I'm trying to make a discord bot for my small server of friends which will pick a random active user when prompted and assign a role to them, remove the role from the previous user who had it, and keep the list of ID's stored in 2 files so that if the bot goes down it can read the IDs from the file and know who has had this role x amount of times and know who the active users were etc.

A lot of the code works but the problem is within this part here:

```
def assign_jester():
    # Randomly selects user to be new jester from the list of users
    jester_role_id = 885183611215683614

    with open(user_log, 'r') as file:
        _users = file.read().split(',')

    new_jester_id = random.choice(_users)
    new_jester, new_jester_username = get_user_details(new_jester_id)
    print('User "{}" selected as new Jester'.format(new_jester_username))

    # Checks who currently has the jester role ready to be removed
    with open(jester_log, 'r') as file:
        _users = file.read().split(',')

    if not is_file_empty(jester_log):
        old_jester_id = _users[-1]
        old_jester, old_jester_username = get_user_details(old_jester_id)
        
        #old_jester.remove_roles(*jester_role_id, reason='No more laughter', atomic=False)
        print('Jester role deleted from user "{}"'.format(old_jester_username))

    # Writing selected users ID to jester log, after the role has been removed from previous
    # This is to make sure that it doesn't delete the newly assigned role
    with open(jester_log, 'a') as file:
        if not is_file_empty(user_log):
            file.write(",")
            file.write(str(new_jester_id))
            print('User "{}" logged to the file as first Jester'.format(new_jester_username))

        else:
            file.write(str(new_jester_id))
            print('User "{}" logged to the file as newest Jester'.format(new_jester_username))

    #new_jester.add_roles(*jester_role_id, reason='Who laughing now, idiot', atomic=False)
    print('Jester role assigned to user "{}"'.format(new_jester_username))
    return


def get_user_details(user_id):
    _server = client.get_guild(829439043753607228)
    print(_server)
    _user = _server.get_member(user_id)
    print(_user)
    _username = _user.name + '#' + _user.discriminator

    return _user, _username
```

My "_user" variable inside the "get_user_details" method returns NoneType and everywhere that I have looked tells me that this code is fine and that it should return the member object like the function should, the _server variable holds the correct data.

I apologise if this is a really stupid question and I've missed something obvious, but my brain is fried from trying to learn all this as I go along so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you enabled Intents?

Comment: @Dominik yes I have this at the top of my code:

"intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.voice_states = True"

Comment: Maybe try enabling all intents

Comment: use `await client.fetch_user(id)`

Comment: is the bot ready at the time you're calling this? like is this in/after on_ready or not?

Answer (score 0):

`get_member(id)` returns the Member **if found** in the Bot's Cache, if it is returning `None` then it was not found, so the I suggest using `await _server.fetch_member(user_id)` instead.